# Convert simple powershell script to Linux script

Tags: linux, powershell, sh

On our build server, I'm adding the build number to the AssemblyInfo.cs file. The script finds the current version in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, then appends the build number, then overwrites the version value. Here's the code:

```
$oldValue = (Get-Content .\\AssemblyInfo.cs | Select-String -pattern 
"AssemblyVersion").Line.Split('"')[1]
$newValue = $oldValue  + "." + $Env:BUILD_NUMBER
(Get-Content .\\AssemblyInfo.cs).replace($oldValue, $newValue) | Set-Content .\\AssemblyInfo.cs
```

I want to make an sh script that does the same thing. I'm able to pull out the version into a variable and print it using these lines:

```
export server_version=`grep AssemblyVersion AssemblyInfo.cs | awk '{split($0,a,"\\""); print a[2]}'| sed "s/'//g" | awk '{$1=$1;print}'`
echo Server version is ${server_version}
sed -i 's/${server_version}/${server_version}.${BUILD_NUMBER}/g' AssemblyInfo.cs
```

However, I haven't had any luck of overwriting the AssemblyVersion. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT, adding input/expected output:

Here is example of AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.3.0")]
```

Then after script where the environment variable build number is another number (Let's say 5 for this example), expected output:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.3.0.5")]
```

Comment: You should provide input and expected output. Also, use double quotes in `sed` if you want to interpolate the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `sed`:

```
BUILD_NUMBER=6; sed -iE "s/(\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(\")(.*)(\"\)\])/\1\2.${BUILD_NUMBER}\3/" AssemblyInfo.cs
```

a bit confusing because you have to escape some things, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux shells, there is a difference between using `'single quotes'` and `"double quotes"`. For instance, `echo '$PATH'` will just print out the string `$PATH`, while `echo "$PATH"` will print out the valute of the environment variable `PATH`.

Thus, your command `sed -i 's/${server_version}/${server_version}.${BUILD_NUMBER}/g' AssemblyInfo.cs` will only replace the the literal string `${server_version}` with the literal string `${server_version}.${BUILD_NUMBER}`, which is not what you want. Change the single quotes to double quotes and `sed -i "s/${server_version}/${server_version}.${BUILD_NUMBER}/g"` will do what you want.